# Right Click event not firing in VSTO code for PowerPoint 2010

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I'm attempting to add a Context Menu option to PowerPoint 2010 that only appears when text is selected.  Unfortunately the WindowBeforeRightClick event does not seem to fire if the mouse is inside of a TextBox.

Is there a different event I need to be listening to or a better way to add that context menu?

Comment: "When text is selected..." do you mean the textbox or the text into the textbox?

Comment: Im also experiencing a similar problem. But its hard to be an area where a few people work on.